# how to use distributive property with $\sqrt{x-2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

with exponents it can be done
$(x-2) ^ 2 = (x-2) * (x-2)$

and then apply distributive property

how to do it with $\sqrt{x-2}$?

Comment: It can't be done with square roots, to be blunt. At least not in any nice way that would remotely resemble the original idea, to my knowledge in any event.

Answer (score 1):

To apply the distributive property, we must be able to distribute (multiply) one of the factors, in the first case $(x-2)$, *over the other set of parenthesis*. This is possible in the first example because expanding any squared binomial yields 2 binomials each raised to the power of 1. It is only for this reason, because 1 is the multiplicative and exponential identity, that we are able to apply multiplication by distribution at this step, because we have eliminated the exponents:

$$
(x-2)(x-2)=x(x-2)-2(x-2)=x^2-4x+4
$$

Let us treat your second case identically to how you began your first:

$$
\sqrt{x-2}=(x-2)^\frac{1}{2}=(x-2)^\frac{1}{4}(x-2)^\frac{1}{4}
$$

Here we cannot apply the distributive property because the exponents have not been eliminated. There is nothing to distribute. It is a special property, then, of a squared binomial, for us to be able to "bypass" the exponents by halving the power.

Answer (score 0):

[Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=expand+sqrt%28x-2%29) is unable to expand it in the way you're thinking, but it does give some possible series expansions at $x=0$, $x=\pi$ and $x=\infty$ using Puiseaux and Taylor series. My own research has led me to conclude that the distributive property does not hold for polynomials raised to fractional exponents, such as your example.